# PHP restructure recursive XML with closing tag on same line? ie <value="blah"/>

Tags: php, xml, recursion

I need to restructure a very large xml source, example is at

http://www.fluffyduck.com.au/sampleXML.xml

I need to modify it for jstree however I'm not sure how to manipulate the data recursively, as  loading it as xml with simpleXml only see's the first 1 user record.

```
<user id="41" username="bsmain" firstname="Boss" lastname="MyTest" fullname="Test Name" email="lalal@test.com" logins="1964" lastseen="11/09/2012">

</user>

to

<user id="41">
    <content><name>bsmain</name></content>
</user>
```

The problem is some xml lines do not have a closing tag such as , but instead look like this :

```
<user id="61" username="underling" firstname="Under" lastname="MyTest" fullname="Test Name" email="lalal@test.com" logins="4" lastseen="08/09/2009"/>
```

If i modify this record and add underling jstree does not recognise it, i'm presuming the /> at the end is the same as  ?

I did want to do this in XML but am thinking it may be easier, to simply somehow parse the xml file 'line by line', read in the line of data explode it perhaps,
then create a new variable storing it with modified contents such as :

```
<user id="61">
    <content><name>bsmain</name>
</user>
```

and on the rows where /> exists at the end, manually insert a  tag.

there has to be a smarter/faster way to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your best bet is to use [`DOMDocument`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/class.domdocument.php) for XML parsing. I have written an example that transforms attributes (excluding the `id` attribute) to content elements:

**Code**

```
<?php
$s =
'<users>' .
    '<user id="61" username="underling" firstname="Under" lastname="MyTest" fullname="Test Name" email="lalal@test.com" logins="4" lastseen="08/09/2009"/>' .
    '<user id="61" username="underling" firstname="Under" lastname="MyTest" fullname="Test Name" email="lalal@test.com" logins="4" lastseen="08/09/2009"/>' .
    '<user id="8" test="testvalue"></user>' .
'</users>';

$doc = new DOMDocument();
$doc->loadXML($s);

$users = $doc->getElementsByTagName("user");
foreach ($users as $user)
{
    if ($user->hasAttributes())
    {
        // create content node
        $content = $user->appendChild($doc->createElement("content"));
        // transform attributes into content elements
        for ($i = 0; $i < $user->attributes->length; $i++)
        {
            $attr = $user->attributes->item($i);
            if (strtolower($attr->name) != "id")
            {
                if ($user->removeAttribute($attr->name))
                {
                    $content->appendChild($doc->createElement($attr->name, $attr->value));
                    $i--;
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

header("Content-Type: text/xml");
echo $doc->saveXML();

?>
```

**Output**

```
<users>
    <user id="61">
        <content>
            <username>underling</username>
            <firstname>Under</firstname>
            <lastname>MyTest</lastname>
            <fullname>Test Name</fullname>
            <email>lalal@test.com</email>
            <logins>4</logins>
            <lastseen>08/09/2009</lastseen>
        </content>
    </user>
    <user id="61">
        <content>
            <username>underling</username>
            <firstname>Under</firstname>
            <lastname>MyTest</lastname>
            <fullname>Test Name</fullname>
            <email>lalal@test.com</email>
            <logins>4</logins>
            <lastseen>08/09/2009</lastseen>
        </content>
    </user>
    <user id="8">
        <content>
            <test>testvalue</test>
        </content>
    </user>
</users>
```

Comment: if you want to test with your url, you can populate `$s` like this: `$s = file_get_contents('http://www.fluffyduck.com.au/sampleXML.xml');`

Comment: wow this is fantastic!! I just tried it quickly with your code and removed the /> off the first record and added a </user> to mimic the parent/child huge relationship in the test xml and it seems to work..!! i will test this out properly first thing in the morning properly *fingers crossed*

Comment: I thought I forgot something hehe, you wouldnt be able to shed some further light on my other issue now? 

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12505381/php-xml-how-to-rename-and-delete-xml-elements-using-simplexml-or-domdocument  thought it best to create new Q